VBA Excel thisworkbook.saved changes inexplicably
My goal is to close a file without being prompted to save after changing a shape, specifically the size of a button; to this end, after changing the button, I set Thisworkbook.saved to True but if I close the file I am still prompted to save.
NB I don't want to turn off the warnings
To reproduce the problem simply create an empty file, add a ActiveX control button on the sheet, save it and then

open the file
manually change the size of the button by pressing the button with the square (the design mode)
from the immediate window launch ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
optional, verify that this has had an effect by typing Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Saved it will answer "True"
try to close the sheet
it will ask if we want to save the changes!!!
answer Cancel
type againDebug.Print ThisWorkbook.Saved it will answer "False" !!!

If instead of the command 3) you do a real save all it will work as expected (i.e. at point 6 the file will close without any questions)
So what else must be done in VBA to fully simulate the Save command?

ThisWorkbook.Close False will close without saving.

The described behavior doesn't happen on my end. Everything is as you described it should be. The described unexpected behavior could occur when you would have an event code that would prevent the expected behavior e.g. a code in the Workbook_BeforeClose or the Workbook_AfterSave event. Have you checked them?

Why not just answer No when asked if you want to save changes?

@VBasic2008 Very strange that you don't experience the problem, to isolate the problem I added an activeX button in an empty file so there is no VBA code in any event. Did you use the same type of button?

@TimWilliams Because the user who knows he hasn't changed anything is rightly annoyed, the one who isn't sure will wonder what he has changed and will answer yes, wasting time.
As for the use of "ThisWorkbook.Close False" it is not possible: without being able to count on the Saved status I wouldn't know when to use the False parameter and when not.

Try putting  Me.Saved = True in the  Workbook_BeforeClose event
